# How to locate points in XY plane in android?

Tags: java, android, draw, android-canvas, point

I need android+java codes to locate points on a xy-coordinate. So whenever I find some points in my main activity, user can go to another activity(i.e. graph activity) and see the points on the  xy-coordinate. How can I create the xy-coordinate view? and how can I locate and show the points on it?

And a question in general- Whenever I want to do a new thing in android+java, I have to ask :) Is there any place to go and find out guides, examples, and such stuff? 
developers.android.com is a great collection of things, but rather complex and gives little information on classes and methods, how to use them, etc.